# How to repair partition table for seagate goflex nas

Tags: data-recovery

I recently had an issue where I kept seeing "no storage device attached" when I was using my goflex home network attached storage device. I have since removed the device and attached it directly to my computer (SATA). However, Ubuntu is not recognizing the partitions.

Answer (score 2):

Open a terminal and install `testdisk`

```
sudo apt-get install testdisk
```

At the command line type `sudo testdisk`. You will be prompted to create a new log file.

- `>[Create]`
- Select the effected disk
- Select `>[EFT GPT]`
- Select `>[Analyze]`

Hopefully, if your disk is not messed up and your partition table is the only thing that's been affected you'll see something like this after a quick search:

```
Disk /dev/sda - 3000 GB / 2794 GiB - CHS 364801 255 63
     Partition               Start        End    Size in sectors
>D MS Data                      504 5860512503 5860512000 [GoFlex Home]
```

Review the file listing (for Seagate shares, select `.users`, otherwise you'll only see Public).

Push enter to continue. Write the partition table. Reboot, and you should have it working long enough to copy your files to a new device.